# How do I fix MSBuild output when calling NodeJS so I don't get weird characters like â”œâ”€â”€?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, utf-8, msbuild

When I call NodeJS from my Visual Studio solution via a pre-build task, I get the following weird characters when building:

```
event-stream@3.1.7 node_modules\event-stream
â”œâ”€â”€ stream-combiner@0.0.4
â”œâ”€â”€ duplexer@0.1.1
â”œâ”€â”€ from@0.1.3
â”œâ”€â”€ pause-stream@0.0.11
â”œâ”€â”€ map-stream@0.1.0
â”œâ”€â”€ split@0.2.10
â””â”€â”€ through@2.3.8
```

Also

```
  [09:57:57] Finished 'ts-emit' after 13 s
  [09:57:57] Starting 'js'...
  [09:58:27] Finished 'js' after 31 s
  [09:58:27] Starting 'Release'...
  [09:58:27] Finished 'Release' after 19 Î¼s
  [09:58:27] Starting 'Prod'...
  [09:58:27] Finished 'Prod' after 13 Î¼s
```

When I run the same command via the cmd.exe prompt, I get this output:

```
event-stream@3.1.7 node_modules\event-stream
├── stream-combiner@0.0.4
├── duplexer@0.1.1
├── from@0.1.3
├── pause-stream@0.0.11
├── map-stream@0.1.0
├── split@0.2.10
└── through@2.3.8
```

Also

```
[10:25:09] Starting 'Debug'...
[10:25:09] Finished 'Debug' after 5.13 μs
[10:25:09] Starting 'Dev'...
[10:25:09] Finished 'Dev' after 3.3 μs
```

How do I get that correct output in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

When you fill out a pre-build task in a csproj, Visual Studio ends up piping that through an Exec command.  For more information on this, see [this great article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/08/691849.aspx) for more information about that.

The Exec command allows you to specify the StdErrEncoding and StdOutEncoding via a couple of arguments, so you need to configure your csproj to use those.

Long story short, you need to add this to your csproj, I added mine under the `<PreBuildEvent>` that I'm using.

```
<Target
    Name="PreBuildEvent"
    Condition="'$(PreBuildEvent)'!=''"
    DependsOnTargets="$(PreBuildEventDependsOn)">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PreBuildEvent)" StdErrEncoding="utf-8"  StdOutEncoding="utf-8"/>
  </Target>
```

The great thing about this fix is that your project's properties will still show the pre-build event in the normal project properties UI, since we didn't mess with the `<PreBuildEvent>` tag in your csproj.

Here's the fixed output

[image: Fixed MSBuild output]